# Grails : Configuring data source at runtime

Tags: grails, database-connection, datasource

I am working on a small grails application. I would like to create a install wizard for the application giving the user the ability to configure data connection settings via a web interface.  Is there a way to stall the data connection and configure the datasource while the application is running?  I would like to do this while maintaining the ability to leverage GORM/Hibernate for all domain objects.  Restarting/reloading the application after configuring the datasource would be ok.

Comment: Check out [this plugin](https://github.com/domurtag/runtime-datasources).

Comment: I would like to leverage GORM/Hibernate after configuring the datasource. I don't think this will work for my scenario.

Comment: If you decide to go with Aram's suggestion below --- the external configuration could be reloaded on the fly with something like this -- def locations = config.grails.config.locations
  locations.each {
   String configFileName = it.split("file:")[1]
   config.merge(new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File(configFileName).text))
  }

Answer (score 0):

In Config.groovy file  add 1 more entry for value of `grails.config.locations`

in result you will have something like this

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:${userHome}/.grails/global-config.groovy",
                           "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
                           "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
                           "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
                           "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy",
                           "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-MyDbconfig.groovy"]
```

In you application after user enters DB connection parameters write it to file

```
"file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-MyDbconfig.groovy"
```

in corresponding format. Like follwoing

```
dataSource{
    url = '...'
    username = '...'
    password = '...'

    properties {
        ...
    }
}
```

save file and restart application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the user should be able to configure the datasource via web interface then you should ask for configuration params since maxActive, maxIdle, etc... Once you have all the params you store anywhere you want.

Inside your Grails application:

```
// grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy

import utils.DataSourceConfigurator

class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        DataSourceConfigurator.configure(servletContext)
    }
}
```

Like this you say to your application that once its ready to run it needs to configure the DataSource first.

```
package utils

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationAttributes
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject

class DataSourceConfigurator {

    private static JSONObject getDSConfig() {
        JSONObject conf = new JSONObject()
        // Go find the configuration wherever you stored it from the web interface, parse it and return it.
        return conf
    }

    public static final configure = { servletContext ->
        if(!servletContext) {
            // Invalid servlet context
            return
        }

        def context = servletContext.getAttribute(ApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
        def ds = context?.dataSourceUnproxied
        if(!ds) {
            // There is no datasource available to configure.
            return
        }

        JSONObject config = getDSConfig()
        if(!config) {
            // No previous configuration saved from web interface.
            return
        }

        ds.setInitialSize(config.initialSize)
        ds.setMaxWait(config.maxWait)
        ds.setMaxActive(config.maxActive)
        ds.setMinIdle(config.minIdle)
        ds.setMaxIdle(config.maxIdle)
        ....
        // There are many other variables to configure. Check them by yourself.
    }
}
```

For more information you could check the documentation regarding DataSource configuration: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#transactionAwareDataSourceProxy